# Query references using joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

**PO Table:**

```
Vendor         PONum     POAmt
ABC Company    10001      1,250.00
DEF Company    10002      3,254.00
GHI Company    10003        854.00
KLM Company    10004      1,572.00
NOP Company    10005      6,000.00
```

**Reference1 Table:**

```
PONum   RefNum
10001   1
10002   2
```

**Reference2 Table:**

```
PONum   RefNum
10003   3
10004   4
```

**Invoice Table:**

```
RefNum   InvNum   InvAmt
1        I0001    1,250.00
2        I0002    3,254.00
3        I0003      854.00
4        I0004    1,572.00
```

**Objective:** to retrieve the invoice number and amount from Invoice Table by referencing using Reference1 and Reference2 Table. if PO Number cannot find in Reference1 then find in Reference2.

```
Vendor         PONum     Amt        InvNum   Amt
ABC Company    10001      1,250.00   I0001    1,250.00
DEF Company    10002      3,254.00   I0002    3,254.00
GHI Company    10003        854.00   I0003      854.00
KLM Company    10004      1,572.00   I0004    1,572.00
NOP Company    10005      6,000.00                0.00
```

**Code:**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t1.Vendor,t1.PONum, t1.POAmt, t3.InvNum, t3.InvAmt  
    FROM PO t1
    LEFT JOIN Reference1 t2 ON t2.PONum = t1.RefNum
    LEFT JOIN Invoice t3 ON t3.RefNum = t2.RefNum
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.Vendor,t1.PONum, t1.POAmt, t3.InvNum, t3.InvAmt  
    FROM PO t1
    LEFT JOIN Reference2 t2 ON t2.PONum = t1.RefNum
    LEFT JOIN Invoice t3 ON t3.RefNum = t2.RefNum
) x
```

This is what I've got so far. Seeking for your assistance for me to achieve the objective. thank you.

Comment: Please tag your db server, thanks

Comment: Curious why you added an outer query to your unioned query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Written for Postgres since you didn't tag a database (Postgres, SQL Server, Oracle, etc...) Should be pretty generic though.

Rationale: Just union your two reference and use that result as the bridge.

Fidde: https://dbfiddle.uk/WBWUstu-

```
CREATE TABLE PO (
    Vendor VARCHAR(100),
    PONum INT PRIMARY KEY,
    POAmt NUMERIC(10, 2)
);

CREATE TABLE Reference1 (
    PONum INT PRIMARY KEY,
    RefNum INT
);

CREATE TABLE Reference2 (
    PONum INT PRIMARY KEY,
    RefNum INT
);

CREATE TABLE Invoice (
    RefNum INT PRIMARY KEY,
    InvNum VARCHAR(10),
    InvAmt NUMERIC(10, 2)
);

INSERT INTO PO (Vendor, PONum, POAmt) VALUES
('ABC Company', 10001, 1250.00),
('DEF Company', 10002, 3254.00),
('GHI Company', 10003, 854.00),
('KLM Company', 10004, 1572.00),
('NOP Company', 10005, 6000.00);

INSERT INTO Reference1 (PONum, RefNum) VALUES
(10001, 1),
(10002, 2);

INSERT INTO Reference2 (PONum, RefNum) VALUES
(10003, 3),
(10004, 4);

INSERT INTO Invoice (RefNum, InvNum, InvAmt) VALUES
(1, 'I0001', 1250.00),
(2, 'I0002', 3254.00),
(3, 'I0003', 854.00),
(4, 'I0004', 1572.00);

select po.Vendor,
       po.PONum, 
       po.POAmt, 
       i.InvNum, 
       coalesce(i.InvAmt, 0) as InvAmt
  from po
  left
  join
       (select *
          from reference1
         union
        select *
          from reference2
       ) r
    on po.poNum = r.poNum
  left
  join Invoice i
    on r.refNum = i.refNum
```

Comment: Better to use UNION ALL since UNION wastes precious electrons distincting values which won't be duplicated

Comment: @siggemannen True

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE WHEN.

```
SELECT
    potable.*,
    invoice.invnum,
    invoice.invamt
FROM
    potable
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ref1 ON ref1.ponum = potable.ponum
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ref2 ON ref2.ponum = potable.ponum
    LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice ON invoice.refNum = 
        CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM invoice WHERE ref1.refnum = invoice.refnum) THEN
            ref1.refNum
        ELSE
            ref2.refNum
        END
```

By doing so, you will get the expected result.

As in the SQL above, we choose to set invoice.refNum = ref1.refNum or ref2.refNum. If it exists in ref1 then invoice.refNum = ref1.refNum else ref2.refNum

Comment: This is a fine approach. Going this route though `ON invoice.refNum = coalesce(ref1.refnum, ref2.refnum)` might be a bit cleaner than the CASE/EXISTS.